# whats wrong in this jquery ajax method call?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, callback

I'm trying to pass the value of a text box to a action method through jquery ajax method. The action method will return a bool value, based on which I need to show a message in my view. I'm trying this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#UserName').blur(function () {
                var name = this.value;
                $.get(@Url.Action("CheckUserName"),{UserName:name},function(data,status){
                if(data==true)
                {
                }
                else
                {
                }
                }););
            })
        });
    </script>
```

Now the problem is, only the if statement is executing! I have checked my action method, its returning true & false accordingly. I need to know what the callback function's parameter "data" is supposed to do? Will it hold the data returned from the action method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing quotes around url.

```
$.get('@Url.Action("CheckUserName")',{UserName:name},function(data,status){
```

Remember, that you need to render a proper javascript, and strings in js need to be enclosed with quotes.

Comment: Hi, I'm having a different problem now. Can you please have a look at the updated question?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in FireBug on the line with `if` statement and see for yourself what is being returned.

Comment: I solved it yesterday, thanks for your time. I just needed to put 3 equal sign in the if statement in between JS code!

Answer (score 0):

In JS code, you need to put 3 equal sign in if statement. thats it!

Comment: Could you please mark my answer as accepted as it was a valid answer for your original question?